# cannot find Meteor index.html

Tags: meteor

I have a simple query, a bit embarrassing as well. Dtube is an app that runs using meteor. I am looking to make some changes on the Dtube Home Page..changing icons and such. I have installed it on a linode. However, I am simply not able to locate the `index` file to make these changes to.

I tried
Locating all the files on linux named `index.html` in the `dtube` directory

Locating all the files containing the string `div class name` ...I was looking for in the `dtube` home page.

Still no luck.

Documentation is scarce and a bit confusing..
Can anyone simply point me to the path I should be looking at to modify the `dtube` homepage?
Someone who knows `Dtube` might be able to answer this.

Comment: Are you looking at the built app or its source code? In the latter case, there may not be a file strictly named "index.html". Looks like that app entry html file is https://github.com/dtube/dtube/blob/master/client/master_layout.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All HTML's and CSS files are in https://github.com/dtube/dtube/tree/master/client

It's necessary rebuild the system to see the results.